# Convert integer enum to string

Tags: c#, enums

considering the following enum:

```
public enum LeadStatus 
{ 
    Cold = 1, 
    Warm = 2, 
    Hot = 3, 
    Quote = 5, 
    Convert = 6 
}
```

How can I convert the integer value back to string when I pull the value from a database. I've tried:

```
DomainModel.LeadStatus status = (DomainModel.LeadStatus)Model.Status;
```

but all I seem to get is "status = 0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enumeration in C# is used to provide names for some known values but ANY integer value is permissible in that enumeration, whether it has a named equivalent or not.

In your example, you have not named a zero value, but your `status` variable initialises to zero. I suspect that it has not changed from this initial value at the point you read it. Therefore, it's string representation is also 0 and you will parse out zero when you parse it.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is Enum.Parse.

*"Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object."*

Here is the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx

Example:

```
enum Colour
{
   Red,
   Green,
   Blue
} 

// ...
Colour c = (Colour) Enum.Parse(typeof(Colour), "Red", true);
```

Courtesy of http://blogs.msdn.com/tims/archive/2004/04/02/106310.aspx

Comment: I tried that first and it gave me the same result:

DomainModel.LeadStatus status = (DomainModel.LeadStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(DomainModel.LeadStatus), Model.Status.ToString());

status = 0

Comment: And Model.status was zero?  I was wondering why it wasn't working, I think an explicit cast from integer to enum should work.

Answer (score 4):

Given "Model.Status" is the integer from the database, it can be restored to the Enum string value with:

```
string status  = Enum.GetName(typeof(DomainModel.LeadStatus), Model.Status);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use ToString() on the enum object

Comment: Is Model.Status also zero? Perhaps you're not reading the value back correctly from the database. ToString() should do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Between [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx) and [Enum.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw.aspx), you should be able to do everything you need.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. A side note about `Enum.Parse`, you need to use `typeof()`, e.g. `Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), "blue");`